# Plotting many 2-point connections

Tags: python, plotly

I want to plot a large amount of connections between two points in Plotly. So assume I have points 1,2,3,4... I want to plot connections 1-2, 3-4, 5-6...  I tried doing a trace for every pair of points where I want to show a connection. This works, but there are so many traces that the resulting html is incredibly slow. As an alternative, I tried to do just one trace that includes all connections, but I don't know how I can remove or at least turn invisible the connections 2-3, 4-5, etc. in my plot. I'm using go.Scatter to create the traces. For reference, I'm including the part of my code that creates the trace.

```
            deliveries = [d for d in deliveries if d.order_type == ot]
            color = order_type_colors[ot]

            lons = zip([stations_dict[delivery.source_location.location_id].lon for delivery in ot_deliveries],
                       [customers_dict[delivery.location.location_id].lon for delivery in ot_deliveries])
            lats = zip([stations_dict[delivery.source_location.location_id].lat for delivery in ot_deliveries],
                       [customers_dict[delivery.location.location_id].lat for delivery in deliveries])

            route_trace = go.Scatter(
                name=str(ot),
                x=[l for ll in lons for l in ll],
                y=[l for ll in lats for l in ll],
                text=[str(delivery.historic_delivery_date) for delivery in ot_deliveries],
                mode="lines",
                showlegend=True,
                visible=False,
                line=dict(width=size_factor, color=color)
            )
```

Comment: does [Scattergl](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#large-data-sets) help performance?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it does but to my great disappointment, only marginally. The html is maybe twice as fast, but still way to slow. Using Scattergl was my first try, as I originally didn't want to lose the individual traces.

Comment: some sample data would help, even some random data in the format of your source data.